# image disappearing while resize the image in firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser

In the Firefox image is disappearing on changing the slider(range). an image is not resizing in Firefox. while changing the slider it is disappearing the image. In chrome, IE browser it is working.
How to resolve this in firefox browser.

```
<input type="range" id="rangeId" min=0 max="100" value="0">
   <img width="275" height="95" ng-show="!!file" ngf-thumbnail="file" id="imageId" />


        //Resize image
        var ranger = document.getElementById('rangeId'),
        image = document.getElementById('imageId'),
        width = image.width,
        height = image.height;

        ranger.onchange = function () {
              debugger;



              image.width = width * (ranger.value / 100);
              image.height =height * (ranger.value / 100);
        }
```

Thnks in advance

Comment: You're missing the image element in your example.

Comment: yes, now edited my post